# How to make undescore symbol to be separator on MySQL FullText search?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, full-text-search

I used MyISAM fulltext search on our old project. When i try to search for some words i don't get values where this word inside underscore symbols (_barrel_);

```
Example table:
mysql> select * from test;
+----+---------------------+

| id | title               |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | BK_43_BARRELS_ONE   |
|  2 | bk_43_BARREL_ONE    |
|  3 | bk-43-BaRrEls-one   |
|  4 | bk 43 barrels one   |
|  5 | b 4 barr on         |
|  6 | barrels             |
|  7 | bk 176 Barrels-goon |
|  8 | bar                 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Query:

```
select * from test where match(title) against('barrel*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

ResultSet:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | title               |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | bk-43-BaRrEls-one   |
|  4 | bk 43 barrels one   |
|  6 | barrels             |
|  7 | bk 176 Barrels-goon |
+----+---------------------+
```

As you can see i don't get record with id = 2 or 1, because MySQL think that underscore is a part of word. That means that i can get records 1,2 only with queries like "BK_43_BARREL*", etc. As i googled, this problem can be solved by adding new collation for character set. I use UTF8 because of Cyrillic database, so i tried to use [this guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ldml-collation-example.html).

I changed utf8 peace of code at /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml:

```
<charset name="utf8">
  <family>Unicode</family>
  <description>UTF-8 Unicode</description>
  <alias>utf-8</alias>
  <collation name="utf8_general_ci" id="33">
   <flag>primary</flag>
   <flag>compiled</flag>
  </collation>
  <collation name="utf8_bin"        id="83">
    <flag>binary</flag>
    <flag>compiled</flag>
  </collation>
  <collation name="utf8_ft_ci"      id="17">
    <flag>binary</flag>
    <flag>compiled</flag>
    <rules>
      <reset>\u0000</reset>
      <s>\u005F</s>
    </rules>
  </collation>
</charset>
```

After MySQL restart all utf8 text looks like this one:

```
1064 - You@0020have@0020an@0020error@0020in@0020your@0020SQL@0020syntax@003b@0020check@0020the@0020manual@0020that@0020corresponds@0020to@0020your@0020MySQL@0020server@0020version@0020for@0020the@0020right@0020syntax@0020to@0020use@0020near@0020@0027RLIKE@003f@003futf8@003f@0027@0020at@0020line@00201
```

So the questions:
1) What i do wrong in Index.xml so all utf8 now broken?
2) What means `<reset>\u0000</reset>` and `<s>\u005F</s>` on LDML syntax? (utf8 broken also when this 2 rules commented).
3) Somewhere i can find a fast guide to LDML syntax?

P.S. i knew that Sphynx rules, but i don't have time to implement this to old project (FullText works fine, except this one problem). And i also know that i should RTM of LDML Syntax, but this cost a lot of time and if someone knew it already... Thx.

P.S.2 This question may look like duplicate on some others, but i can't find exactly the same one (UTF8, Cyrillic text, Underscore problem, Index.xml LDML Syntax).

Comment: I think, this is important. MySQL version is 5.5.43. LDML syntax a little bit different.

Comment: A guess:  `reset` threw out all punctuation; you needed to add back in all the old punctuation, plus '_'.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. I successfully created new collation and applied it to test table. This works with simple equaluation, but not for fullsearch. I will edit my question soon when get time.